# Email pdf of specific sheet name with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a pdf using google apps script and while this works to get the pdf

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var blob=ss.getAs('application/pdf').setName('report.pdf')
```

it won't work if I try to put a specific sheet name, as in

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
```

it throws an error for getAs

Anybody know how to do this so I can get a specific sheet name?  Note, I need the sheet name since this is done by a trigger and without that the script fails because there is no sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

@Allen, I think you can not print directly by calling the active sheet. A decent workaround is selecting the active sheet and copying it to a new spreadsheet and use getAs().

> [**getAs(contentType)**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype)
>
> Return the data inside this object as a blob converted to the
>    specified content type. This method adds the appropriate extension to
>    the filename — for example, "myfile.pdf". However, it assumes that the
>    part of the filename that follows the last period (if any) is an
>    existing extension that should be replaced. Consequently,
>    "ChristmasList.12.25.2014" will become "ChristmasList.12.25.pdf".

And add this after using getAs:

> [**getBytes()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getbytes)
>
> Gets the data stored in this blob.

Here is the sample code:

```
var pdf = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
```

That is based on this [github code example](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885).